# Google Cloud - Error Reporting Client Libraries

Tags: python, kubernetes, error-reporting, google-cloud-logging, google-cloud-error-reporting

I'd like to use the Google Error Reporting Client library (from google.cloud import error_reporting).

Basically, you instantiate a client:
`client = error_reporting.Client(service="my_script", version="my_version")`
and then you can raise error using:

1. `client.report("my message")` or
2. `client.report_exception()` when an exception is caught

I have 3 environments (prod, staging and dev). They are each setup on their own Kubernetes cluster (with their own namespace). When I look at Google Cloud Error Reporting dashboard, I would to quickly locate on which environment and which class/script the error was raised.

Using service is a natural choice to describe the class/script but what about the environment?
What is the best practice? Should I use the version to store that, e.g. version="staging_0.0.2"?

Many thanks in advance
Cheers,
Lamp'

Comment: Can you explain in more details what you've tried so far ?

Comment: I think you should provide your feedback to Google using the [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com). Two things surprise me about this. First, that you can't apply an arbitrary set of labels to errors. Second, that the service doesn't instrument known Resource Types like GKE [containers](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/resources#tag_gke_container).

Comment: See: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/181167949

Answer (score 0):

I think the Error Reporting service is deficient (see comment above).

Since you're using Kubernetes, how about naming your Error Reporting services to reflect Kubernetes Service names: `${service}.${namespace}.svc.cluster.local`?

You could|should replace the internal `cluster.local` domain part with some unique external specifier (FQDN) to your cluster: `$[service}.${namespace}.${cluster}`

> **NOTE** These needn't be actual Kubernetes Services but some way for you to uniquely identify the thing within a Kubernetes cluster `my_script.errorreporting.${namespace}.${cluster}`